# Dismiss View Controller iOS

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, dismiss

[image: Second View Controller Hierarchy]

I used the `self.dimiss(animated:true, compilation: nil)` method to dismiss my second ViewController and it worked just fine until I applied some changes only to my UI in Storyboard, the code of the  Second View Controller remained the same, but for some reason it stopped working.

I use Xcode Beta Version 8.0 beta 3 (8S174q)

Answer (score 1):

its not compilation its completion:nil, moreover its not dimiss its dismiss.
you have been using wrong syntax.
use 
self.dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
instead

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong syntax and notations in your code. The correct syntax is

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```